# Offset appears in image content when scrolling UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am getting some strange behaviour when scrolling a TableView of custom UITableView cells.

When the app first opens, the content is fine:

[image: Initial load of the app]

But if I scroll my view some offsets appear in the embedded UIImageViews:

[image: State after scrolling]

I have removed all layout constraints, and the problem still occurs.

I am at loss for reasons why this happens; any help is welcomed!

Here's my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *StrechCellIdentifier = @"StrechCell";

    //Place regular strechable cells.
    GFStrechCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:StrechCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = (GFStrechCell*) [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:StrechCellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = @"Chez Julien";

    cell.descriptionLabel.text = @"A yummy place!";

    cell.descriptionLabel.hidden = YES;

    [cell.restaurantImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"restaurant%i.png", (indexPath.row%5 + 1)]]];

    if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0){
        [cell.favoriteButton.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favoriteButtonPressed.png"]];
    } else {
        [cell.favoriteButton.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favoriteButton.png"]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

`GFStrechCell` is just a simple subclass of call with elements pointing to IBOutlets in storyboard:

[image: Storyboard section]

Comment: Could you show some code on how you're adding the image into the cell? My guess is that you're not adding it to the cell's contentView, or something along those line. But I can't tell until I see some code.

Comment: @Rob I have added some code but there's nothing special.. I do everything using storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's odd, try this out just to see if it works

Below:

```
[cell.restaurantImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"restaurant%i.png", (indexPath.row%5 + 1)]]];
```

Try adding:

```
CGRect restaurantImageFrame = cell.restaurantImage.frame;
restaurantImageFrame.origin = CGPointZero; //or whatever it should be
cell.restaurantImage.frame = restaurantImageFrame;
```

This will set the image's origin to (0,0).

Edit: you could also try adding the following line instead.

```
[cell.restaurantImage sizeToFit];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but it doesn't help. Same effect

Comment: I added code to log the image's frame, and it does move to {15, 17} after a while! However, if I add your code, the origin stays at {0, 0}, but visually the problem is still there. Upvoted for helpfulness.

Comment: Found the solution! Used your frame/origin code, but in the layoutSubviews method of the custom cell class!

Comment: just as a side note, if the code was working but it was taking a while to work, it is possible that you may have been executing the code from a thread that is not the main thread. usually, when you update UI outside the main frame, the changes take a while to take effect, that's why you should always do it from the main thread. But it may have been something else. but anyway, i'm glad it helped.